# Twitter URL for returning /user_timeline Searches

Tags: twitter, filter

I may be completely overlooking something but I can't seem to filter the user_timeline results by keyword in the REST api.

example:

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/starbucks.json?q=pumpkin
```

returns all the results, not the ones filtered by the word 'pumpkin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the method to do this if anybody else needs it,

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+pumpkin+from:starbucks
```

remember to URL encode special chars after (?) , the top string didn't need it.